# Skipping arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function my_func(a, b){
    if(typeof(a) !== 'undefined'){
        // do stuff
    }

    return b;
}
```

How can I call this function will only the second argument?  In other words, I want **a** to be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_func(undefined, b);
```